# Synergy using internet connection instead of local connection

Tags: networking, synergy

I've had Synergy installed between two machines and it work flawlessly before, but I'm experienced a strange condition with my new desktop. When I bring my mouse from my server PC to my client, the cursor is extremely laggy. I also see (through NetLimiter) that my upload/download fluctuates greatly.

I've tried disabling my firewall. What could be causing Synergy to use my internet connection rather than local network to transmit data?

Comment: I found something similar to your issue. have a look here:
http://superuser.com/questions/292926/use-lan-to-interface-synergy-while-having-wifi-connected-to-internet